# Помогите написать парсер

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, python-2.x

Вопрос №1
Суть такова. Имеется файл с таким содержимым:

```
persist.operator.    u:object_r:usp_srv_prop:s0 
persist.mtk_usp    u:object_r:usp_srv_prop:s0
persist.mtk_clr_code_support    u:object_r:usp_prop:s0
persist.flight_mode_md_off    u:object_r:usp_prop:s0
```

и тому подобное. Нужен скрипт, который бы парсил этот файл и создавал новый с таким содержимым:

```
type *_prop, property_type;
```

где `*_prop` это выражение между `u:object_r:` и `:s0`

Решено. (см. 1-2 ответы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('property_contexts.txt', encoding='utf-8') as input_file: 
    with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if len(line) > 2 and line[0] != '#':
                try:
                    # Разбиваем строку на части по символу ':'
                    # Из полученного списка берем предпоследний элемент
                    prop = line.split(':')[-2] 
                except IndexError:
                    continue

                # Подставляем эту часть в новую строку и записываем в файл
                newline = 'type {}, property_type;\n'.format(prop)
                output_file.write(newline)
```

Результат в файле `output.txt`:

```
type usp_srv_prop, property_type;
type usp_srv_prop, property_type;
type usp_prop, property_type;
type usp_prop, property_type;
```

Comment: Лучше всегда указывайте кодировку файла при записи/чтении, т.к. по умолчанию это системная, например `open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: при выполнении его получается Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 3, in <module>
    prop = line.split(':')[-2] 
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, исправил ответ.

Comment: @AndrewGoldman, у вас есть пустые строки или в строки, в которых меньше 2 символов `:` в строке? :) @Andrey, как вариант, можете добавить проверку на количество символом `:`, сделав `split` убедиться что предпоследний есть, либо сделайте try/except в цикле и там гасите исключение :)

Comment: @gil9red, да пустые строки есть. Вы не пинайте, я только начинаю в это лезть :) и можно как-то  добавить исключение для строк, которые начинаются на #  ?

Comment: @AndrewGoldman вы можете залить ваш файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: @Andrey https://github.com/SonyCustoms/device_sony_tuba/blob/rebase/sepolicy/property_contexts

Comment: @AndrewGoldman обложился проверками, вроде бы сейчас работает как нужно. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Можно к этому подключить регулярки, например:

```
import re

with open('property_contexts.txt', encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            match = re.search('u:object_r:(.+?):s0', line)
            if not match:
                continue

            # Достаем захваченное регуляркой выражение (символы в круглых скобках)
            prop = match.group(1)

            # Подставляем эту часть в новую строку и записываем в файл
            newline = 'type {}, property_type;\n'.format(prop)
            output_file.write(newline)
```

Вариант через `findall`:

```
with open('property_contexts.txt', encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
    text = input_file.read()

    with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        for prop in re.findall('u:object_r:(.+?):s0', text):
            # Подставляем эту часть в новую строку и записываем в файл
            newline = 'type {}, property_type;\n'.format(prop)
            output_file.write(newline)
```

---

**PS.**

Можно немного оптимизировать код через компиляцию регулярок:

```
pattern = re.compile('u:object_r:(.+?):s0')
```

и использовать так:

```
pattern.search(line)
# или
pattern.findall(text)
```

Comment: а как быть если имеется не только data_file_type, а и file_type в одном файле? https://github.com/SonyCustoms/device_sony_tuba/blob/rebase/sepolicy/file_contexts#L125-L126 
Взял за основу Ваш вариант для пробы. Можно ли как-то сделать проверку на data_file_type и наоборот в данном решении?

Comment: @AndrewGoldman, непонятно в чем суть вашего вопроса :) эти оба попадают под шаблон данных из вопроса (`u:object_r:(.+?):s0`), если нужно их различать, то напишите как это делать (например по тексту между `:` или по первым символам строки)

Comment: да, их нужно различать ибо сеполиси это штука страшная :) т.к file_type и data_file_type 2 разных вещи. Вроде бы по тексту между _
в 1 комментарии ссылка на файл

Comment: @AndrewGoldman, комментарии плохо подходят по ТЗ или уточнее его, поэтому сделайте правку в вопрос, добавив туда и ссылку, и пример данных, и что должно получиться :)

Comment: обновил, дописал