# Помогите дописать парсер

Tags: python, парсер

Исходя из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953454/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80) вопроса.

Суть такова. Имеется файл с таким содержимым:

```
/idd(/.*)?  u:object_r:idd_data_file:s0
/qns(/.*)?  u:object_r:qns_file:s0
/dev/BU64245GWZAF(/.*)? u:object_r:BU64245GWZAF_device:s0
/dev/socket/tfsw(/.*)? u:object_r:tfsw_socket:s0
```

и так далее. Нужно получить на выходе файл (или файлы) с таким содержимым:

```
type idd_data_file, data_file_type;
type qns_file, file_type;
type BU64245GWZAF_device, dev_type;
type tfsw_socket, socket_type;
```

исходя из того что `data_file_type`, `file_type`, `dev_type`, `socket_type` 4 РАЗНЫХ типа.

Также стоит взять во внимание, что файл (снизу будет ссылка на него) имеет пустые строки и строки, начинающиеся с #, которые должны быть проигнорированы.

[Ссылка на файл](https://github.com/SonyCustoms/device_sony_tuba/blob/rebase/sepolicy/file_contexts)

Надеюсь, всё правильно и доходчиво расписал..
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что @strawdog правильно выбрал направление, в котором нужно двигаться, но так как   во входящих данных есть много элементов каждого типа, то наверное нужно указывать в `types` не конкретные варианты элементов, а тип:

```
types = (
    ('_data_file', 'data_file_type, file_type'),
    ('_file', 'file_type'),
    ('_device', 'dev_type'),
    ('_socket', 'socket_type')
)

with open('file_contexts.txt', encoding='utf-8') as input_file: 
    with open('output_file_contexts.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if len(line) > 2 and line[0] != '#':
                try:
                    # Разбиваем строку на части по символу ':'
                    # Из полученного списка берем предпоследний элемент
                    prop = line.split(':')[-2] 
                except IndexError:
                    continue

                # Сначала проверяем тип data_file, потом file,
                # потом все остальное. Если тип соответствует,
                # то пишем в файл и прекращаем проверку строки.
                for t in types:
                    if t[0] in prop:
                        newline = 'type {}, {};\n'.format(prop, t[1])
                        output_file.write(newline)
                        break
```

Comment: @AndrewGoldman то есть на входе одна строка, а на выходе вы получили две? вы уверены, что вывод именно такой? Я создал отдельный файл с единственной строкой из вашего примера и на выходе получил только `type system_sensor_data_file, data_file_type;`

Comment: Да, именно так. Вот коммит с изменениями https://github.com/andrwgldmn/SEcontexts_parser/commit/55b8a9fc28ae71412da5857045f0d6b4530cabf0
должно получится как тут: https://gist.github.com/andrwgldmn/526dfc698b4a58ee37dbb918bb6bfe3d
+ попробуйте эту же строку но с ('_data_file', 'data_file_type'),
    ('_file', 'file_type') одновременно, чтобы воспроизвести проблему

Comment: @AndrewGoldman ну все правильно, в коммите немного не тот, код, который  я предложил - вы убрали `break` и теперь он не останавливается, ели нашел совпадение, а продолжает проверку этой же строки. отсюда и дубликаты.

Comment: @AndrewGoldman объясните, какая логика вам нужна? Если найден тип `_data_file'`, то выводить `data_file_type, file_type;`, а если `_file`, то только `file_type;`?

Comment: Именно так, да.

Comment: Изменил `types`, взгляните. `break` нужно вернуть обратно. Это то, что вам нужно?

Comment: именно, то что и требовалось. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Общее решение по работе с файлом вам уже изложили.
Дальше- дело техники:

```
types ={"idd_data_file":"data_file_type", "qns_file":"file_type", "BU64245GWZAF_device":"dev_type", "tfsw_socket":"socket_type"}

#Вместо исходного файла:
indata = '''/idd(/.*)?  u:object_r:idd_data_file:s0
/qns(/.*)?  u:object_r:qns_file:s0
/dev/BU64245GWZAF(/.*)? u:object_r:BU64245GWZAF_device:s0
/dev/socket/tfsw(/.*)? u:object_r:tfsw_socket:s0'''

for line in indata.split("\n"):
    mytype = line.split(":")[-2]
    print(f"type {mytype}, {types[mytype]};")
```

Получите:

```
type idd_data_file, data_file_type;
type qns_file, file_type;
type BU64245GWZAF_device, dev_type;
type tfsw_socket, socket_type;
```

Проще говоря, как вариант, заведите словарь (здесь - `types`), и в предложенном вам ранее [решении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953454/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80), вместо `newline = 'type {}, property_type;\n'.format(prop)` используйте

```
newline = f"type {prop}, {types[prop]};\n"
```

Comment: а можно без словаря обойтись? ибо придётся добавлять 300+ строчек + у каждого устройства свой file_contexts (но это уже больше к сборке андроида) со своими значениями.

Comment: @AndrewGoldman что словарь, что кортеж (как в другом ответе), что отдельный файл - вам нужен источник информации, откуда брать тип данных. Тем более, у вас нет строгого соответствия между данными и типом (если `data_file` и `file` можно регуляркой однозначно превратить в `data_file_type` и `file_type` соответственно, то `device` нужно превратить в `dev`, и таких вариантов может быть море - просто регуляркой не угадаешь).